# TikZ/pgfplots: How to make tikzpcture fit the parent figure/subfigure float environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In this MWE, how can I make `tikzpicture` fit the allocated space of parent float environment (`figure` or `subfigure`)?

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,caption,subcaption,mwe}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false]
                \addplot graphics [
                    xmin=0,
                    xmax=50,
                    ymin=0,
                    ymax=150,
                ] {example-image-a};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    %
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false]
                \addplot graphics [
                    xmin=0,
                    xmax=50,
                    ymin=0,
                    ymax=150,
                ] {example-image-b};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    %
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false]
                \addplot graphics [
                    xmin=0,
                    xmax=50,
                    ymin=0,
                    ymax=150,
                ] {example-image-c};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

### Edit

The output of code below doesn't make subfigures span over all `\textwidth` despite making each subfigure width equal to `0.33\textwidth`.

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,width=\textwidth]
                \addplot graphics [
                    xmin=0,
                    xmax=50,
                    ymin=0,
                    ymax=150,
                ] {example-image-a};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    %
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,width=\textwidth]
                \addplot graphics [
                    xmin=0,
                    xmax=50,
                    ymin=0,
                    ymax=150,
                ] {example-image-b};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    %
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,width=\textwidth]
                \addplot graphics [
                    xmin=0,
                    xmax=50,
                    ymin=0,
                    ymax=150,
                ] {example-image-c};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
```

[image]

Comment: Add `width=\textwidth` to the `axis` options? Or is that insufficient?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for your comment, regarding my edit, there is a gap between the subfigures I don't know how to control it; additionally, the `tikzpicture` doesn't seem to fit well the subfigure width.

Comment: Well, there is a space between each of the subfigures, add `%` after the first two `\end{subfigure}`s. And yes, the `width` setting of `pgfplots` is only approximate, as it doesn't actually measure the width of the ticklabels/axis labels. You could `\resizebox` it, though that isn't ideal.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Apart from subfigure approach, I would be grateful if you could provide me any answer that makes these `ikzpicture`s span the whole `textwidth` with control over the spacing between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the third subfigure on a separate line is that you have a space between the subfigures. A linebreak in the code is the same as a space, so you need a `%` after `\end{subfigure}`. I.e., instead of

```
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin..
```

you need

```
\end{subfigure}%
%
\begin..
```

or

```
\end{subfigure}%
\begin..
```

See e.g. [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453)

The second problem is that the `width` key for a  `pgfplots` `axis` isn't actually accurate. What `pgfplots` does is to assume that the ticklabels and axis labels take up an 45pt of space outside the axis itself. So it takes the specified width, subtracts 45pt, and uses this width for the axis.

You can't change the 45pt to something else, but you can calculate your own axis width, and use the `scale only axis` key to say that the `width` parameter applies to the axis disregarding ticklabels/axis labels.

A cruder method is to put the whole `tikzpicture` in a `\resizebox`, and simply scale it up to the width of the subfigure. The problem of this is that fonts are resized as well.

Last, note that if you don't have captions for these, then the `subfigure` environments are somewhat pointless, and can be discarded.

The first row shows the effect of `\resizebox`, in the second I used a calculated width for the axes, and in the third the same, but without `subfigure` environments.
The `showframe` package prints a frame around the text area, those are the lines seen in the screenshot:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,subcaption,showframe}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,width=\textwidth]
                \addplot graphics [
                    xmin=0,
                    xmax=50,
                    ymin=0,
                    ymax=150,
                ] {example-image-a};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{subfigure}%
    %
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,width=\textwidth]
                \addplot graphics [
                    xmin=0,
                    xmax=50,
                    ymin=0,
                    ymax=150,
                ] {example-image-b};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{subfigure}%
    %
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,width=\textwidth]
                \addplot graphics [
                    xmin=0,
                    xmax=50,
                    ymin=0,
                    ymax=150,
                ] {example-image-c};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{subfigure}

    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\myaxiswidth}{0.33\textwidth-width(" 150 ")}% subtract width of widest ticklabel, with a space on each side
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,width=\myaxiswidth,scale only axis]
                \addplot graphics [
                    xmin=0,
                    xmax=50,
                    ymin=0,
                    ymax=150,
                ] {example-image-a};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}%
    %
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,width=\myaxiswidth,scale only axis]
                \addplot graphics [
                    xmin=0,
                    xmax=50,
                    ymin=0,
                    ymax=150,
                ] {example-image-b};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}%
    %
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,width=\myaxiswidth,scale only axis]
                \addplot graphics [
                    xmin=0,
                    xmax=50,
                    ymin=0,
                    ymax=150,
                ] {example-image-c};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}


        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,width=\myaxiswidth,scale only axis]
                \addplot graphics [
                    xmin=0,
                    xmax=50,
                    ymin=0,
                    ymax=150,
                ] {example-image-a};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,width=\myaxiswidth,scale only axis]
                \addplot graphics [
                    xmin=0,
                    xmax=50,
                    ymin=0,
                    ymax=150,
                ] {example-image-b};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,width=\myaxiswidth,scale only axis]
                \addplot graphics [
                    xmin=0,
                    xmax=50,
                    ymin=0,
                    ymax=150,
                ] {example-image-c};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your informative answer. I am so sorry, but I have a naive question: what is the meaning of `width(" 150 ")`? I changed this number, and I found it affects the size of `tikzpicture` inside the `subfigure`. However, I don't know what its unit is and why it is enclosed by double quotes. Additionally, was `150` calculated or set by trial and error?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou `" 150 "` is not a number, it's a string. Chosen because the widest yticklabel is 150. The `pgf` math function `width("...")` calculates the width of `...`. Instead of `width(" 150 ")` you could write say `15pt`, and vary `15pt` till you found a reasonable value.

Comment: And no need to be so sorry for that, it's an honest question.