# TikZ/pgfplots: How to evenly distribute tikzpicture subfigures after hiding axes labels?

Tags: pgfplots

Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350066/2288), when setting `ytick=\empty` for the second and third subfigures, the subfigures are not evenly distributed, so how can I fix this output by letting all the subfigures have the same width and evenly distributed over `textwidth`?

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,caption,subcaption,mwe,showframe}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\myaxiswidth}{0.33\textwidth-width(" 300 ")}% subtract width of widest ticklabel, with a space on each side
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,width=\myaxiswidth, height=0.3\textheight, scale only axis]
                \addplot graphics [xmin=0, xmax=50, ymin=0, ymax=150] {example-image-a};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}%
    %
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,width=\myaxiswidth, height=0.3\textheight, scale only axis, ytick=\empty]
                \addplot graphics [xmin=0, xmax=50, ymin=0, ymax=150] {example-image-b};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}%
    %
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,width=\myaxiswidth, height=0.3\textheight, scale only axis, ytick=\empty]
                \addplot graphics [xmin=0, xmax=50, ymin=0, ymax=150] {example-image-c};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Will you not be adding individual captions to these plots?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I apologise for late reply. Yes, later I will add some captions to these subfiguers, so this why I followed this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the differing space here is a combination of factors. First, because the first plot is wider than the two last, the distance from the right side of the axis to the edge of the `subfigure` is smaller for the first than for the last two.

Further, the two last plots are narrower than the `subfigure` environments, and by default text inside these are aligned to the left. To fix that part, add `\centering` at the start of each `subfigure` environment, but that isn't enough to get equal distance between axis 1&2 and 2&3, due to what is described in the first paragraph above.

Now, there might well be other ways, I'm definitely not good at finding elegant solutions, but the workaround I thought of is to use `\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]` for all three plots. `trim axis left` is a style that changes the bounding box of the `tikzpicture` so that anything to the left of the `axis` (ticklabels, ylabel) are not considered when determining the bounding box. This does have the unwanted side effect that the ticklabels of the first axis may go into the left margin, but you can counter that by adding some horizontal space before the first subfigure. (See code example below.)

I also made the `subfigure`s a bit narrower and used `\hfill` between them to add space that fills out the line.

That said, if you are not going to add individual captions, then I would say you using the wrong tool for the job, and making the code longer than necessary. I would suggest adding the `groupplots` library of `pgfplots`, and adding all three images in the same `groupplot` environment. (I didn't think of this for your previous question.) `groupplots` makes this sort of thing very easy to do.

With the help of `\captionof` from the `caption` package you can also add subcaptions, by placing `\node`s with a specified `text width` relative to the axes, example below. Some juggling with the `figure` counter seems to be needed to get correct cross references though.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,caption,subcaption,showframe}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
          group name=G,
          group size=3 by 1,
          y descriptions at=edge left,
          horizontal sep=10pt % adjust as needed
        },
        enlargelimits=false,
        width=0.33\textwidth-width("300"),
        height=0.3\textheight,
        scale only axis]

      \nextgroupplot
      \addplot graphics [xmin=0, xmax=50, ymin=0, ymax=150] {example-image-a};
      \nextgroupplot
      \addplot graphics [xmin=0, xmax=50, ymin=0, ymax=150] {example-image-b};
      \nextgroupplot
      \addplot graphics [xmin=0, xmax=50, ymin=0, ymax=150] {example-image-c};
    \end{groupplot}
    \refstepcounter{figure} % to get correct 
     \node [text width=0.33\textwidth-width("300"),below right,align=center] at (G c1r1.south west) {\captionof{subfigure}{Subcaption for the first plot\label{a}}};
     \node [text width=0.33\textwidth-width("300"),below right,align=center] at (G c2r1.south west) {\captionof{subfigure}{Subcaption for the second plot}};
     \node [text width=0.33\textwidth-width("300"),below right,align=center] at (G c3r1.south west) {\captionof{subfigure}{Subcaption for the third plot}};
     \addtocounter{figure}{-1}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{..}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\myaxiswidth}{0.33\textwidth-width("300 ")}
  \hspace*{\dimexpr0.33\textwidth-\myaxiswidth}%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering % added
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
      \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,width=\myaxiswidth, height=0.3\textheight, scale only axis]
        \addplot graphics [xmin=0, xmax=50, ymin=0, ymax=150] {example-image-a};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Subcaption for the first plot}
    \label{b}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering % added
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
      \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,width=\myaxiswidth, height=0.3\textheight, scale only axis, ytick=\empty]
        \addplot graphics [xmin=0, xmax=50, ymin=0, ymax=150] {example-image-b};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Subcaption for the second plot}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering % added
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
      \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,width=\myaxiswidth, height=0.3\textheight, scale only axis, ytick=\empty]
        \addplot graphics [xmin=0, xmax=50, ymin=0, ymax=150] {example-image-c};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Subcaption for the third plot}    
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{...}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Top is for `groupplots` code, bottom for `subfigure` code.

[image]

Comment: Great answer as usual. For groupplots approach, how can I add caption or subcation for each figure?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou On second thought I'm not sure how great it actually is, didn't try adding captions, so that might look a bit weird. But I think I can add a method for adding captions to a groupplot.

Comment: Comprehensive and inofrmative answer, I couldn't ask for more. Many thanks.